# How can i use onchange function to change price of account invoice line price_unit

Tags: odoo

I would like to use onchange to set account invoice price to a default price set in res.partner.  Could anyone give me an example of this ?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples of onchange in addons.

For example, if you want to change the value of 'name' field and want to set product's name based on selected product:

```
def onchange_product_id(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id, context=None):
    if product_id:
        prod = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, product_id, context=context)
        return {'value': {'name': prod.name}}
    return {}
```

Comment: Thanks, i've been looking at these examples for days but still confused. Could you give an example where account.invoice.line fetch information from res.partner settings? This would be verrrry much appreciated.

Comment: can u tell me that what kind of info(data) u want to fetch from res.partner?

Comment: I want to have a product on res.partner where the price_unit is calculated according to interest. This means that the price_unit changes according to interest added to the product. So when i choose the product in acount invoice line it automatically sets the price.

Comment: Do you have an association between 'product' and res.partner?

Comment: class res_partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    _columns = {
        'interest': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Interest'),
        'delay': fields.integer('Days of delay', help='Set the number of days before invoicing'),
        'percent': fields.float('Percent',                               digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account'),
help='Set the percent for delayed invoices'),
        
    }

res_partner()

Comment: But based on which field you want to apply onchange?
I mean do you want to fetch product (product associated with partner) when user select partner in account.invoice form?

Comment: It should be based on partner. So if i choose partner and then product in invoice line then the price_unit should be based on the paramaters set for that partner

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
So u want to set price_unit in invoice_line based on partner.
But I am wondering that how will you get value for price_unit from res.partner.
Do u have any field which stores price_unit in res.partner or u want to calculation inside onchange?

Comment: I would like to have the calculate it in onchange

Comment: I'm trying to figure out which is best, to store calculation outside onchange or inside. So how would I write the func. if I wanted to have the calculation stored in a field?

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your_invoice_view.xml:

```
<field name="product_id" on_change="product_id_change(product_id, parent.partner_id, context)"/>
```

Write onchange in your_invoice.py under "invoice_line" model(class):

```
def onchange_product_id_change(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id, partner_id context=None):
if product_id and partner_id:
    product_brw = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, product_id, context=context)
    partner_brw = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, uid, partner_id, context=context)
    /*write your logic */
    return {'value': {'price_unit': your calculated value}}
return {}
```

Comment: You can write your calculation in this onchange in my submitted code by accessing product & partner's record.
Hope your problem will get solved by this.

Comment: I am getting the following error:                                              return {'value': {'price_unit': partner_brw.(price_unit)}}
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I tried to add a product when partner is chosen but no product is added. in this instance, I used your example by adding a field instead of a calculated value. Any idea why product is not added? I also tried to add a fixed amount but nothing happens. Example for fixed amount is:         columns {'rate': fields.float('Minimum amount', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account')),

Comment: Hi Arya, the code you supplied me did not really work. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Hello JoeB,
I have just provided you the example for ur problem, now u have to write ur logic by make use of that code.